# My netty TCP/IP server stops listenning few hours after starting

Tags: sockets, tcp, netty

I have written TCP/IP server using Netty4.0 running on a Linux machine listening to small GPS tracking devices. I have been facing weird problem, which is server stops listening to them in a sudden several hours after I starts it. There is any error log I can see and still server is running. It looks like only channel is not working. When I run a client to do health check, the client socket is still alive and keep sending packet to the server but server does not get it. 
If you have any idea how to solve it, please tell me about it. It would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to tell without more informations. I would check different things like if there was an OOM exception or with telnet if the server really refuse connections etc. Also jstack may show you if there is some deadlock etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, I cannot find any error message in the log. Anyway, I will try as what you say too.